# EF.Functions.Contains with more than one property references

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, full-text-search

I want to use SQL Server's Full Text Search [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) through EF.Functions.Contains for doing full text search in my database.

Everything works fine with one parameter as property reference but I can find no way to use more than one property reference.

C# code with one property reference:

```
 var test = await dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Column1, searchText)).ToListAsync();
```

Will be successfully translated to sql code like bellow:

```
select * from MyTable where contains(Column1 , N'SearchText')
```

But how can I write a C# code which give me the bellow sql code:

```
select * from MyTable where contains((Column1, Column2) , N'SearchText')
```

This way doesn't work:

```
Expression<Func<MyTable, object>>[] propertyReferences =  { x => x.Column1 , x=> x.Column2 }; 
var test = await dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(propertyReferences, searchText)).ToListAsync();
```

And also this way doesn't work:

```
var test = await dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(new {x.Column1 , x.Column2 }, searchText)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: couldnt you use two contains with logicals ANDs inside the where? something like  `var test = await dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Column1, searchText) && EF.Functions.Contains(x.Column2, searchText)).ToListAsync();`

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Comment: why not? you get the x where column1 contains the search text and column2 contains the search text. is that not what you want?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you can according to https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10462 unless you use the OR thing

Comment: Or use FromSqlRaw, which allows using all the arguments of the function.

Comment: Raw SQL is probably your only option. But you can compose it with other operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already mentioned in the comments above you need to combine the two method calls for every column. in this way you can combine as much columns as you want.

with a logical AND

```
var test = await dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Column1, searchText) && EF.Functions.Contains(x.Column2, searchText)).ToListAsync();
```

with a logical OR

```
var test = await dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Column1, searchText) || EF.Functions.Contains(x.Column2, searchText)).ToListAsync();
```